# New GeoServer WFS error NoSuchAuthorityCodeException

Tags: geoserver, wfs, syntax

What is causing this error?

org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:4326," from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "IdentifiedObject".

https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/hyphaegeo/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&TYPENAME=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&BBOX=562073.76526905409991741,4185632.69297888176515698,563852.27126529649831355,4187445.67907886626198888,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326:

Clicking on this link doesn't produce the error, but pasting it into the address bar does. More importantly, QGIS fails to load the layer with

[image: XML error in Chrome]

*2020-05-20T12:17:15 CRITICAL Layer Greenview test (Prescott) : Download of features for layer hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest failed or partially failed: Error when parsing GetFeature response : Error: not well-formed (invalid token) on line 1, column 1804. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5*

I have verified:

- the EPSG.data file is in its place
- the WFS is on for the workspace
- 4326 is listed in the WFS settings page

Other than that settings are mostly OOB.

Comment: I get no error on that request - if you are seeing something in the log file please [edit] the question with that information

Comment: The bbox values are incorrect for epsg:4326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

`<ows:ExceptionText>
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code &quot;EPSG:4326,&quot; from authority &quot;European Petroleum Survey Group&quot; found for object of type &quot;IdentifiedObject&quot;. No code &quot;EPSG:4326,&quot; from authority &quot;European Petroleum Survey Group&quot; found for object of type &quot;IdentifiedObject&quot;.
</ows:ExceptionText>`

Is occurring because you have a spurious trailing colon in your request

> https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/hyphaegeo/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&TYPENAME=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=10000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&BBOX=562073.76526905409991741,4185632.69297888176515698,563852.27126529649831355,4187445.67907886626198888,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326:

You have `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326:` but it should be `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&`

The query though still fails to return any values because the bounding box is incorrect for EPSG:4326 (values should be no greater than +/-90,+/-180,+/-90,+/-180 decimal degrees)

Comment: Thank you! Good points. So why would QGIS ask for planar coordinates when the crs is a spherical one? The request is also generated automatically by QGIS, so where does the spurious trailing colon come from??

Comment: What projection is the QGIS project in

Comment: I believe it was a project using 6420, CA state plane III. I tested using a fresh project with 4326 and I get the same error without any bounding box being part of the request. I guess that is due to the trailing colon. Any ideas about the source of that issue?

Comment: `https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/hyphaegeo/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&typename=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&version=2.0.0` shows WFS is complex type, and QGIS may not be able to handle it directly, there is a GML application schema plugin that you could try

Comment: However, `https://geo.hyphae.design/geoserver/hyphaegeo/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&typenames=hyphaegeo:PrescottGreenviewTest&version=2.0.0&count=1&` gives an invalid response ~ `s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'name' in element 'element'. Recorded reason: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '0count' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.`   and this is likely the real cause

Comment: So one obvious takeaway seems to be don't import tables with columns that start with a numeral.

Comment: If its your service, then you should fix it. Otherwise you can try filtering out all  invalid attribute names, otherwise you can try using a non XML output format